# C# read XML file with nested tables

Tags: c#, xml

Hi How can I use C# to read a xml file with nested tables and display with drill down data like this. I tried the DataSet.ReadXml method, but the tables are stored individually without relationship. They can be access by ds.Tables[1], ds.Tables[2]. I want to be able to show relationship, so I can display data like below.

ParentTable_Column1, ChildTable1_Column1, ChildTable2_Column1

Here is the schema

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://sbmex.dsh.cms.gov" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://sbmex.dsh.cms.gov" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="T5_MemberDates">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MemberStartDate" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="MemberEndDate" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:date"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="EPSExtract">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="FileInformation" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="FileId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="FileCreateDateTime" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                            <xs:element name="StateCd" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="CoverageYear" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:short"/>
                            <xs:element name="PayeeId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="StateTPID" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="IssuerId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Policy" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="OriginalSBMIFileId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:long"/>
                            <xs:element name="OriginalSBMIExtractDateTime" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                            <xs:element name="CMSPolicyVersionDateTime" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                            <xs:element name="QHPId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="ExchangeAssignedPolicyId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="ExchangeAssignedSubscriberId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="PolicyStartDate" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:date"/>
                            <xs:element name="PolicyEndDate" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:date"/>
                            <xs:element name="EffectuationInd" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="InsuranceLineCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="MemberInformation" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="ExchangeAssignedMemberId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                        <xs:element name="SubscriberIndicator" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element name="MemberLastName" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element name="MemberFirstName" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:choice>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="NameSuffix" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                <xs:element name="BirthDate" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:date"/>
                                                <xs:element name="SocialSecurityNumber" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                                <xs:element name="PostalCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                                                    <xs:element name="LanguageQualifierCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="LanguageCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="GenderCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                <xs:element name="TobaccoUseCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                <xs:element name="MemberDates" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="T5_MemberDates"/>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="MemberMiddleName" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                <xs:choice>
                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                        <xs:element name="NameSuffix" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                        <xs:element name="BirthDate" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:date"/>
                                                        <xs:element name="SocialSecurityNumber" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                                        <xs:element name="PostalCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                                        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                                                            <xs:element name="LanguageQualifierCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                            <xs:element name="LanguageCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                        <xs:element name="GenderCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                        <xs:element name="TobaccoUseCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                        <xs:element name="MemberDates" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="T5_MemberDates"/>
                                                    </xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                        <xs:element name="BirthDate" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:date"/>
                                                        <xs:choice>
                                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                                <xs:element name="SocialSecurityNumber" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                                                <xs:element name="PostalCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                                                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                                                                    <xs:element name="LanguageQualifierCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                    <xs:element name="LanguageCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                </xs:sequence>
                                                                <xs:element name="GenderCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                <xs:element name="TobaccoUseCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                <xs:element name="MemberDates" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="T5_MemberDates"/>
                                                            </xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                                <xs:element name="PostalCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                                                <xs:element name="GenderCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                <xs:element name="TobaccoUseCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                <xs:element name="MemberDates" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="T5_MemberDates"/>
                                                            </xs:sequence>
                                                        </xs:choice>
                                                    </xs:sequence>
                                                </xs:choice>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="BirthDate" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:date"/>
                                                <xs:element name="SocialSecurityNumber" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                                <xs:element name="PostalCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                                                    <xs:element name="LanguageQualifierCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="LanguageCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="GenderCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                <xs:element name="TobaccoUseCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                <xs:element name="MemberDates" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="T5_MemberDates"/>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:choice>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="FinancialInformation" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="FinancialEffectiveStartDate" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:date"/>
                                        <xs:element name="FinancialEffectiveEndDate" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:date"/>
                                        <xs:element name="MonthlyTotalPremiumAmount" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:decimal"/>
                                        <xs:element name="MonthlyTotalIndividualResponsibilityAmount" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:decimal"/>
                                        <xs:choice>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="MonthlyCSRAmount" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:decimal"/>
                                                <xs:element name="CSRVariantId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:byte"/>
                                                <xs:element name="RatingArea" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="MonthlyAPTCAmount" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:decimal"/>
                                                <xs:element name="MonthlyCSRAmount" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:decimal"/>
                                                <xs:element name="CSRVariantId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:byte"/>
                                                <xs:element name="RatingArea" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:choice>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="RecentErrorReporting" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ActivityInd" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="PolicyError" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="SourceFileId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:long"/>
                                        <xs:element name="SourceFileCreateDateTime" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                                        <xs:element name="RecordControlNumber" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                        <xs:element name="ExchangeAssignedPolicyId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                        <xs:element name="QHPId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element name="ExchangeAssignedSubscriberId" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:int"/>
                                        <xs:element name="Error" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="ErrorCode" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="ErrorDescription" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="ElementInError" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="AdditionalErrorInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>



<EPSExtract xmlns="http://sbmex.dsh.cms.gov">
    <FileInformation>
        <FileId>Abc123</FileId>
        <FileCreateDateTime>2017-12-21T09:10:31.798000</FileCreateDateTime>
        <StateCd>CA</StateCd>
        <CoverageYear>2018</CoverageYear>
        <PayeeId>A102001</PayeeId>
        <StateTPID>FEP0099CA</StateTPID>
        <IssuerId>123455</IssuerId>
    </FileInformation>
    <Policy xmlns="http://sbmex.dsh.cms.gov">
        <OriginalSBMIFileId>987654</OriginalSBMIFileId>
        <OriginalSBMIExtractDateTime>2017-12-01T01:33:49</OriginalSBMIExtractDateTime>
        <CMSPolicyVersionDateTime>2017-12-07T15:14:49</CMSPolicyVersionDateTime>
        <QHPId>123456</QHPId>
        <ExchangeAssignedPolicyId>55555</ExchangeAssignedPolicyId>
        <ExchangeAssignedSubscriberId>17858469</ExchangeAssignedSubscriberId>
        <PolicyStartDate>2018-01-01</PolicyStartDate>
        <PolicyEndDate>2018-12-31</PolicyEndDate>
        <EffectuationInd>Y</EffectuationInd>
        <InsuranceLineCode>HLT</InsuranceLineCode>
        <MemberInformation>
            <ExchangeAssignedMemberId>17858479</ExchangeAssignedMemberId>
            <SubscriberIndicator>N</SubscriberIndicator>
            <MemberLastName>Thomson</MemberLastName>
            <MemberFirstName>James</MemberFirstName>
            <BirthDate>1988-11-18</BirthDate>
            <SocialSecurityNumber>885954478</SocialSecurityNumber>
            <PostalCode>94112</PostalCode>
            <LanguageQualifierCode>LE</LanguageQualifierCode>
            <LanguageCode>SPA</LanguageCode>
            <GenderCode>M</GenderCode>
            <TobaccoUseCode>U</TobaccoUseCode>
            <MemberDates>
                <MemberStartDate>2018-01-01</MemberStartDate>
                <MemberEndDate>2018-12-31</MemberEndDate>
            </MemberDates>
        </MemberInformation>
        <MemberInformation>
            <ExchangeAssignedMemberId>695414</ExchangeAssignedMemberId>
            <SubscriberIndicator>Y</SubscriberIndicator>
            <MemberLastName>Martin</MemberLastName>
            <MemberFirstName>Yan</MemberFirstName>
            <BirthDate>1969-07-07</BirthDate>
            <SocialSecurityNumber>845591254</SocialSecurityNumber>
            <PostalCode>94112</PostalCode>
            <LanguageQualifierCode>LE</LanguageQualifierCode>
            <LanguageCode>ENG</LanguageCode>
            <GenderCode>M</GenderCode>
            <TobaccoUseCode>U</TobaccoUseCode>
            <MemberDates>
                <MemberStartDate>2018-01-01</MemberStartDate>
                <MemberEndDate>2018-12-31</MemberEndDate>
            </MemberDates>
        </MemberInformation>
        <FinancialInformation>
            <FinancialEffectiveStartDate>2018-01-01</FinancialEffectiveStartDate>
            <FinancialEffectiveEndDate>2018-12-31</FinancialEffectiveEndDate>
            <MonthlyTotalPremiumAmount>929</MonthlyTotalPremiumAmount>
            <MonthlyTotalIndividualResponsibilityAmount>55.08</MonthlyTotalIndividualResponsibilityAmount>
            <MonthlyAPTCAmount>873.92</MonthlyAPTCAmount>
            <MonthlyCSRAmount>204.38</MonthlyCSRAmount>
            <CSRVariantId>05</CSRVariantId>
            <RatingArea>R-667</RatingArea>
        </FinancialInformation>
    </Policy>
</EPSExtract>
```

Comment: I know your problem.  When reading xml into a data set the tag level are as follows 1) Root Tag : Dataset name 2) 2nd level tag : Table names 3) 3rd level tag : Columns names 4) 4th level tags is the row data.  When you have more than 4 layers of tags the additional data tables are created in VS that have no relationships.  So you need custom parsing.  I can create any number of tables for you, but is is easier to have actual sample of xml with at least two items of each type in sample.

Comment: Here is my code

Comment: Code is missing.  Please add the xml file (not schema).

Comment: Just added code  at the bottom. Thanks

Comment: You just posted personal information to the web!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code below.  I put all the data into one table, but you can create multiple tables and add keys as needed so you have common fields in table.  There is nothing wrong with putting all the data into one column except it will use more space in the database.  Splitting common data into table saves space in a database.   I put two columns of data into the table so you have to finish the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication19
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("FileId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("FileCreateDateTime", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("StateCd", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("CoverageYear", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("PayeeId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("StateTPID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("IssuerId", typeof(string));

            dt.Columns.Add("OriginalSBMIFileId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("OriginalSBMIExtractDateTime", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("CMSPolicyVersionDateTime", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("QHPId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ExchangeAssignedPolicyId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ExchangeAssignedSubscriberId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("PolicyStartDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("PolicyEndDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("EffectuationInd", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("InsuranceLineCode", typeof(string));

            dt.Columns.Add("ExchangeAssignedMemberId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SubscriberIndicator", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("MemberLastName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("MemberFirstName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("BirthDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("SocialSecurityNumber", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("PostalCode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("LanguageQualifierCode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("LanguageCode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("GenderCode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("TobaccoUseCode", typeof(string));

            dt.Columns.Add("FinancialEffectiveStartDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("FinancialEffectiveEndDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("MonthlyTotalPremiumAmount", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("MonthlyTotalIndividualResponsibilityAmount", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("MonthlyAPTCAmount", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("MonthlyCSRAmount", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("CSRVariantId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("RatingArea", typeof(string));

            XElement fileInfo = doc.Descendants(ns + "FileInformation").FirstOrDefault();

            string fileId = (string)fileInfo.Element(ns + "FileId");
            DateTime fileCreateDate = (DateTime)fileInfo.Element(ns + "FileCreateDateTime");
            string stateCd = (string)fileInfo.Element(ns + "StateCd");
            int coverageYear = (int)fileInfo.Element(ns + "CoverageYear");
            string payeeId = (string)fileInfo.Element(ns + "PayeeId");
            string stateID = (string)fileInfo.Element(ns + "StateTPID");
            string issueID = (string)fileInfo.Element(ns + "IssuerId");

            XElement policy = doc.Descendants(ns + "Policy").FirstOrDefault();


            string originalFileId = (string)policy.Element(ns + "OriginalSBMIFileId");
            DateTime originalExactDate = (DateTime)policy.Element(ns + "OriginalSBMIExtractDateTime");
            string policyVersion = (string)policy.Element(ns + "CMSPolicyVersionDateTime");
            string qhpId = (string)policy.Element(ns + "QHPId");
            string assignedPolicyId = (string)policy.Element(ns + "ExchangeAssignedPolicyId");
            string exchangeSubscriberId = (string)policy.Element(ns + "ExchangeAssignedSubscriberId");
            DateTime policyStartDate = (DateTime)policy.Element(ns + "PolicyStartDate");
            DateTime policyEndDate = (DateTime)policy.Element(ns + "PolicyEndDate");
            string effectuationInd = (string)policy.Element(ns + "EffectuationInd");
            string insuranceLineCode = (string)policy.Element(ns + "InsuranceLineCode");

            XElement financialInformation = policy.Element(ns + "FinancialInformation");

            DateTime financialEffectiveStartDate = (DateTime)financialInformation.Element(ns + "FinancialEffectiveStartDate");
            DateTime financialEffectiveEndDate = (DateTime)financialInformation.Element(ns + "FinancialEffectiveEndDate");
            decimal monthlyTotalPremiumAmount = (decimal)financialInformation.Element(ns + "MonthlyTotalPremiumAmount");
            decimal monthlyTotalIndividualResponsibilityAmount = (decimal)financialInformation.Element(ns + "MonthlyTotalIndividualResponsibilityAmount");
            decimal monthlyAPTCAmount = (decimal)financialInformation.Element(ns + "MonthlyAPTCAmount");
            decimal monthlyCSRAmount = (decimal)financialInformation.Element(ns + "MonthlyCSRAmount");
            string CSRVariantId = (string)financialInformation.Element(ns + "CSRVariantId");
            string ratingArea = (string)financialInformation.Element(ns + "RatingArea");

            List<XElement> memberInformations = policy.Elements(ns + "MemberInformation").ToList();

            foreach (XElement memberInformation in memberInformations)
            {
                string exchangeAssignedMemberId = (string)memberInformation.Element(ns + "ExchangeAssignedMemberId");
                string SubscriberIndicator = (string)memberInformation.Element(ns + "SubscriberIndicator");
                string MemberLastName = (string)memberInformation.Element(ns + "MemberLastName");
                string MemberFirstName = (string)memberInformation.Element(ns + "MemberFirstName");
                DateTime BirthDate = (DateTime)memberInformation.Element(ns + "BirthDate");
                string SocialSecurityNumber = (string)memberInformation.Element(ns + "SocialSecurityNumber");
                string PostalCode = (string)memberInformation.Element(ns + "PostalCode");
                string LanguageQualifierCode = (string)memberInformation.Element(ns + "LanguageQualifierCode");
                string LanguageCode = (string)memberInformation.Element(ns + "LanguageCode");
                string GenderCode = (string)memberInformation.Element(ns + "GenderCode");
                string TobaccoUseCode = (string)memberInformation.Element(ns + "TobaccoUseCode");
                DateTime MemberStartDate = (DateTime)memberInformation.Descendants(ns + "MemberStartDate").FirstOrDefault();
                DateTime MemberEndDate = (DateTime)memberInformation.Descendants(ns + "MemberEndDate").FirstOrDefault();

                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                // sample of adding rows to table, need to complete
                newRow["ratingArea"] = ratingArea;
                newRow["ExchangeAssignedMemberId"] = exchangeAssignedMemberId;


            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much jdweng. This is exactly what I wanted.